# Create a clickable circle 10 times using javascript and if I click on it, it shows number in center how many time I clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practicing javascript. I want to have 10 circles with different colors. I can create 10 circles using html and css, but need help with javascript. For each circle show the number of times it is clicked on. If I click on blue 3 times, it should show 3 in the center of circle

```
    <style>
        .circle{
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 3px;
            background: blue;
            border: 2px solid black;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="circle">
        3
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck with the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way

```js
var circleSelector = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");

var myClickFunction = function() {
  var previousNumber = +this.innerHTML || 0;
  this.innerHTML = previousNumber + 1;
};

for (var i = 0; i < circleSelector.length; i++) {
  circleSelector[i].addEventListener('click', myClickFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  0
</div>

<div class="circle red">
  0
</div>

<div class="circle gray">
  0
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, create the circle divs like so:

`<div class="circle" onclick="increment_circle(this);">0</div>`

The `onclick` attribute is important, it will trigger the script.

You will want to create the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function increment_circle(element){
  var current = parseInt(element.innerHTML);
  current++;
  element.innerHTML = current;
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

```js
function incrementCircle(element) {
  var current = parseInt(element.innerHTML);
  current++;
  element.innerHTML = current;
}
```

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:blue;">0</div>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:red;">0</div>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:green;">0</div>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:orange;">0</div>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:yellow;">0</div>
  <div class="circle" onclick="incrementCircle(this);" style="background-color:gray;">0</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Rich If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer using the check mark.

Comment: what if I only need upto 10 circles and all with different colors and I click on circle 1- 3 times, it would shows clicked 3 times?

Comment: @Rich You will want to copy-paste the div shown, and add a `style="background-color: something;"` attribute to each. Take the `background` out of the style tag.

Comment: @Rich Edited with complete snippet/demo of the correct code.

Comment: Please use separation of concerns and place JS in one place, not half in HTML, half in script. Use `addEventListener` instead.